# How to create simple tree menu using PHP or HTML but without JS?

Tags: php, html, css, menu

I want to create simple tree menu. But I can only use PHP or HTML. In my case I am not allowed to include any JavaScripts.

Comment: Css is also not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

[Stu Nichols at CSS Play](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/)  would be a good place to start looking at.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it's bad form. But you could use the GET method with links to pass values to your PHP file then return the appropriate response to the page.

ie.

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET['link'])){
        $_GET['link'] = ""; // if not set, gets dummy value
    }

    $link = $_GET['link'];

    function showPage($link){
        switch($link){
            case "home":
                echo "<a href='page.php?link=homesub1'>Home Sub Menu 1</a><br>";
                echo "<a href='page.php?link=homesub2'>Home Sub Menu 2</a>";
                break;
            case "other":
                echo "<a href='page.php?link=osub1'>Other Page Sub Menu 1</a><br>";
                echo "<a href='page.php?link=osub2'>Other Page Sub Menu 2</a>";
                break;
        }
    }
?>
<a href="page.php?link=home">HOME</a>
<a href="page.php?link=other">Some Page</a>

<br>
<?php
    if($link != ""){
        showPage($link);
    }
?>
```

Obviously, a lot of thought has to be put in for the design to work. It's a disaster but it gets the job done.

Note: 
A better approach to this would be to convince whoever is in-charge to let you use JS/jQuery.